# docker-compose - CORS policy error when connecting to back-end from browser

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a few Docker containers to deploy a web application. I have a PostgreSQL container, a Spring back-end container and a React front-end container. The interaction between the back-end and database works fine, but I'm struggling to set up the interaction between the front-end and back-end. I want to use docker-compose and after setting it up, I want to test this set-up using the browser on my computer (the host).

I followed some tutorials and looked online, but after all changes I made, I still get this error when using my browser on `localhost:80`.

[image]

My docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
   container_name: backend
   image: "backend:latest"
   build:
    context: ./backend
   ports:
    - 5002:8080
    
  frontend:
   container_name: frontend
   image: "frontend:latest"
   build:
    context: ./frontend
   ports:
    - 80:80

networks: 
  default: 
    external: 
      name: my-network
```

The Dockerfile in the `front-end` directory looks like this.

```
# build environment
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR .
ENV PATH node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build ./build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

After some research, I added a CORS configuration to the nginx.conf, but this doesn't seems to solve the problem.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  frontend;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    #
    # CORS config for nginx
    #
    location /api {
    
        # 
    # the request made to localhost/api are enabled to CORS
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    
    # 
    # the request made to localhost/api forwards to backend:8080 service
    #
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
   }
}
```

I don't really know where to look for the problem. To make API calls, I use axios and it is set up like this.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5002/api"
});
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see if any response is received in the network tab of the developer tools? The browser might report cors if it doesn't get a response. And if there is a response, please provide the response headers.

Comment: @Anton
Response Headers: 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2022 14:20:42 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: as we can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't present, meaning the issue is on the server side. i haven't used nginx though so i don't think i can help you any further